# Can't get Visual Studio to target the correct Android version

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a problem getting Xamarin.Android to target the newest version of Android.

The problem arised when I tried installing the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps NuGet package, that required me to run at least Android 8.

From my Android SDK manager, I can see that Android 8 and 8.1 is the only SDK platforms installed:

[image]

However, when I start a new project in Visual Studio 2017, and go into the project properties, and extend the Compile using Android version dropdown, it's populated like this:

[image]

So here I can choose only 7.1 (that is marked as latest platform), and 8.0 and 8.1 is marked with (Requires installation). Android 7.1 SDK that VS uses is not even installed on my machine.

So the questions is: What do I have to do to select Android 8.1 as the Target Framework inside Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I have to do to select Android 8.1 as the Target Framework inside Visual Studio?

In your VS, Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager, you will see Android SDK for VS, it default path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`.

In your AS, Android SDK's path is `C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Now, you can change the VS's Android SDK's path to `C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`, but we don't suggest you do that, it may cause VS compilation errors at some point, and by then you cannot find the cause of the problem.

So, you can download the Android 8 from VS again.

Comment: That was the problem. I installed Android 8 from the SDK manager inside Android Studio, and thought that was systemwide, but I actually had to isntall it again from inside VS Tools. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction :)

Comment: Glad it help you!